# How to Edit a File in VS2010 & TFS w/o checking the file out

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working with TFS 2010 and I need to edit a file localy without checking it out.  I want to be able to edit the file in VS2010, is this possible?

Comment: @Vlad: VS2010 and TFS are both tools specific to developers, so this does belong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defective "Save as" dialog Rossini refers to above is a known bug in VS 2010, with the official response being "Won't fix"

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765219/tfs2010-save-as-dialogue-does-not-overwrite-an-un-checked-out-file-when-solution-is-open#

This effectively makes it so you cannot use "Edit: Do Nothing" and removing the read-only attribute as a way to work with single files offline without a check-out.  So from all the work I have done the answer to this question is "you cannot", at least not in any effective way.

The alternatives (none of which are reasonable, usable, or accomplish what you want in scratchpad file editing) are to take your whole solution offline or only load the file directly in a separate instance of Visual Studio (that is, outside of the Solution), at which point you lose a bunch of references and Intellisense and might as well use Notepad++.

I just wanted to get this final information out for those (like me) who have searched for a way to do this.  The last time I checked this was still broken in VS 2012 as well.

[Edit]  I have not looked at any of the plugins or addons mentioned, only off-the-shelf Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit a local file in Visual Studio without checking it out by remove the read-only attribute on the file (DOS command: attrib -r). The editable file will not show up in your workspace's pending changes.

Leaving a lot of editable (writable in TFS-term) files in your local workspace will increase the number of merge conflicts when you do a get latest, and someone else has changed these files. You can search for these editable but not checked out files in your local workspace using the TFS command line power tool: "tfpt.exe online".

More information on the tfpt commands can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/16/493401.aspx).

Comment: I tried removing the read only attribute, however VS2010 automatically checks out the file anyway.  What you are suggesting worked in Visual SourceSafe, however it does not work now that I've upgraded to Team Foundation Server.

Comment: This has worked for me all the time. Did you remove the attribute, then open VS and the file is checked out? Does VS say anything about checking out files, etc.?

Comment: As you suggested I tried removing the read only attribute, then starting VS2010 and changing the file.  The file is still automatically checked out.  VS2010 does not prompt me to check out files, it does it automatically.

Comment: You're actually correct. My bad, I forgot that I used this only when my TFS server was already offline so VS couldn't check out the file even if it wants to. In fact, when the TFS server is offline, VS will disconnect your solution from TFS, and you'll have to manually add it back (using tfpt online) later.

Comment: I think you have two options here: 1) Make VS think your solution is connected against some bogus TFS server and thus set your solution to offline. This might require deleting some cache and clean up the solution file. 2) Use a tfs power tool to make VS work offline with TFS (tfpt tweakui). See here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/p3net/pages/tfs-2010-in-offline-mode.aspx - I haven't tried this myself (don't have the powertool downloaded on my machine) but it sounds like that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell VS / TFS not to check out on edit, Tools / Options / Source Control / Environment

Change Saving to "Prompt for checkout" and Editing to "Do nothing".

[image: TFS Checkout Options]

Comment: Technically this does allow me to edit the file with out checking it out.  However I need to save the file too otherwise there is no point in modifing the file.  I want to recompile my project with my local changes.  When I save the file VS2010 will prompt me to check out the file, and my choices are "check out" or "cancel".  When I hit cancel the file is not saved.

Comment: @Rossini, this might be a dumb question! Why is the file being checked out a problem?

Comment: I want to write some throw away code for experimental use and another developer has the file checked out and we disallow multiple checkouts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Get the file and then disconnect from TFS (Work Offline). You will not check out the file.

Or just edit the file and do not check it in. Undo the changes and the file will never be checked-in.

Comment: This doesn't work, when I disconnect from TFS it closes my solution.  When I open the solution again, VS2010 automatically reconnects to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this:

1. Edit your VS options like this:
   [image]
2. Edit your file and click Save. At this point, you'll get a warning dialog like this:
   [image]
3. Hit Ok and then modify the file's read-only attribute and then save again. This will allow you to save your edits without checking out.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, however at step 3 when I hit save (after removing the read only attribute) I get the dialog "file already exists. Do you want to replace it?" to which I click "Yes". The dialog closes and I'm left looking at the "Save File As" dialog, and the file is not saved. When I click save again, I again am prompted to replace the file.  I've also tried to delete the file first.  When the file is deleted and I click Save in the "Save File As" dialog nothing happens.  The file is not saved, and the dialog remains unchanged on the screen.

Comment: This does seem to be bug to me. As an workaround, remove readonly attribute and  edit the file in another editor (like Notepad++) and then save it. VS will either prompt or automatically reload the file (based on your settings) and you can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008 from the menu choose Tools|Options|Source Control|Environment.

Check **Allow checked-in items to be edited**.

I'm guessing this will also work in VS2010.

Comment: this allows me to edit checked in items, however I am unable to save the file.  As in James Reed's answer when I save the file VS2010 will automatically check out the file.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question "is this possible" the answer is yes depending on what you want to do.

You can edit the files and do whatever you want to do locally without a risk of checking the file. Make sure your solution is closed before you run the TFPT tweakui command then open it back up inside Team Explorer.  Make sure you are in the correct folder when running the command.  Use TFS 2008 Powertools to do this.

**However...**

When you sync back up, it will check the files out automatically that have the read-only flag removed.  So what you would need to do is add the flag back and rollback your changes after you were done with your local testing.

Maybe you can describe why it is important that the file not be checked out in the first place and the community can help you work around that issue?  For everyday development, this workflow is somewhat error-prone and requiring the use of TFS Powertools is pretty heavy-handed in my opinion.

At any rate, I hope that gets you headed in the right direction there are plenty of other comments here that are helpful as well

Comment: I would prefer to not take the entire solution off line, however if that’s the only way to do it that might be acceptable.  
The TFPT tweakui sounds like it’ll do what I want.  However I don’t have that command.  I’ve installed TFS 2005 Power Tools, the TFS 2008 Power Tools, and the TFS 2010 Power tools, and none of these have the tweakui option.  After reading your post I downloaded the latest version of power tools for TFS 2008 & TFS 2010, and I still don’t have the tweakui option.  
I have other options for TFPT like annotate, bind, query … but not tweakUI
Why don't I have that option?

Comment: Uninstall all three and re-install 2008.  Run the command again.  Make sure you are in the correct directory and running the command prompt as an admin.

Comment: Once you path to the correct folder which is most likely "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008 Power Tools" type tfpt help and you should see the command on the list.  From there, type TFPT tweakui and you should have no problems from there.

Answer (score -3):

'I want to recompile my project with my local changes'. You should be working WITH your source control, not against it.

Make a version of your code with your local changes. Check that in. Now label it. Go back and get a version of your code prior to your revision for local changes, edit the file pasting in that content, and  check that in. Now when you compile local, get the labeled version of your code, and recompile. Yes, you will have the changes checked in, but the latest version of the code will not have the version with your local changes. Be creative with your label, and put a descriptive label on it so other developers will understand what it is for.

This is assuming it is a single file. In VSS, you could do something similar with 'pinning' the code. Regardless of the number of check ins after the pin, other users would only get the pinned version. In TFS, there is no equivalent to pinning (thank the gods). You could do something similar with branching, but you certainly wouldn't want to do that for a single, throw away piece of code for experimental local use.

Comment: The change I want to make is exactly as you describe a throw away piece of code for experimental purposes.  I don’t want the changes to ever go into source control.  Also there are times when another developer has the file checked out, so I can’t just check the file out and undo my changes.

Comment: Then I would say allow it to check out, then undo changes after you are finished. No one else should get the changes as you have not checked them in.

Comment: This person is obviously, someone that has been brainwashed by the Sourcesafe way of doing things!...